# Response.Rdirect is not working from Modal dialg in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012

I have a web site which uses response.redirect to navigate pages. This web site is being used  by several other places ( different domain or from same domain).

The problem comes when the calling web sites use IE 10 and it opens my web site in modal window.

This is the call from other web sites.

```
window.showModalDialog('mypage1.aspx',null,'dialogWidth:600px;dialogHeight:480px;');"
```

In that case, the redirected page mypage1.aspx ( from my site) gets opened in a new window. Now, mypage1.aspx has a 'Next' button which calls

```
Response.Redirect("mypage2.aspx",true);
```

This 'next' button from 'mypage1.aspx' opens a **new window** for mypage2.aspx  - not in the dialog itself. I would like to have other web sites open my web site pages in the **same dialog** . How should I do it ?

Comment: You say this is only happening in IE10? In other browsers the pages are coming up in the modal window?

Comment: I have not tried many other browsers except Mozilla and Chrome. Pages are working as expected there. IE 10 and IE 11 seems to be not working.

Comment: Where is the `showModalDialog()` function coming from? I need to see that function's code. That is most likely where the problem is.

Comment: @jwatts1980, showModalDialog is from other client web sites. It could be any other page like 'client.aspx'  with a button in it. 'code'  <input id="clientButton" type="button" value="Open web site" onclick="window.showModalDialog('mypage1.aspx',null,'dialogWidth:600px;dialogHeight:480px;');" /> 'code'

Comment: It is not recommended that you use this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog " Deprecated
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended for you to use `window.showModalDialog()`. It's functionality has been deprecated and any support that you get may stop working at any time.
[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog)

> Deprecated.  This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>   Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps
>   using it may break at any time.